# CausalImpact: defining seasonal data parameters

Tags: python, r, time-series, statsmodels, causality

I am trying to figure out how to use the Python port of [CausalImpact](https://github.com/dafiti/causalimpact) package.

In the examples [notebook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/dafiti/causalimpact/blob/master/examples/getting_started.ipynb), there is a section on working with seasonal data.

It is still unclear to me how to define the `nseasons` parameter.

In the notebook example:

`ci = CausalImpact(season_data, pre_period, post_period,
                  nseasons=[{'period': 7, 'harmonics': 2}, {'period': 30, 'harmonics': 5}])`

`neasons` takes a list of dicts. I believe setting the `'period':7`  is used to denote seasonality at a weekly level, and `'period':30` at a monthly level, but I'm not 100% sure. I also do not understand, however, what the `harmonics` parameter represents.

The dataset I'm working with right now is the daily aggregates of sales for an online retailer. Ultimately, I would like to have the model consider the fact that seasonality can occur at the weekly, monthly, and quarterly level. How can I set the `nseasons` parameter to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found some useful parameters when I aggregated my transactional sales data to weekly level and then set these parameters:

`nseasons=[{'period':4},{'period':12},{'period': 52}]`

because for weekly sales data that span several years, we expected seasonal trends to be observed at month (4 weeks), quarter (12 weeks), and year (52 weeks) levels.